# Is there a general location where we can direct questioners who obviously need a better foundation in their topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Often there are perfectly good answers to people's questions, that the original asker is not able to understand because they have a total lack of understanding of the language they are using, or about programming in general.

This invariably leads to almost an argument with the OP that they need to learn the basics of their craft/language before they start tackling advanced topics.

I.e. we have "Stack Overflow is not a forum", but do we have "Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a first programming book"?

Answer (score 1):

But... Stack Overflow **is** suitable for new programmers.

In the absence of examples, I'd argue that if someone posts an answer to a question that the poster does not understand then the problem is with the answer (as in they should elaborate or clarify their answer), not the asker - even if it is a perfectly good answer in every other regard, if it isn't targeted at the knowledge level of the asker then its not going to be particularly helpful to them.

Comment: It's suitable for new programmers, yes. But you won't be able to teach yourself, say, C#, without some other reference material in addition to StackOverflow. I.e. if you ask a C# question people are going to assume you know how to compile a C# file.

Comment: @Billy I don't think I'm following your argument - perhaps it would help if you posted an example question?